# What does this symbol $\sum\bigoplus M_i$ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

Let $R$ be a ring  and $\{M_i\}$ a family of $R$-modules, then what does this symbol
$\sum\bigoplus M_i$ mean? This symbol appeared in the following paper,

> *Eben Matlis*, [**Injective modules over Noetherian rings**](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=99360), *Pacific J. Math.* **8** (1958), 511--528.

Is it just the direct sum $\oplus M_i$ we use now?

Comment: It would be so much easier to answer that if you provide the reference and/or link to that paper.

Comment: The symbol $\sum\bigoplus Mi$ appears in Proposition 2.1 in E.Matlis's paper "Injective modules over Noetherian rings", the link is: http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1103039896

Answer (score 2):

Most likely it is the direct sum; this symbol is still alive in Banach space theory.